# Juju - Bootstrap failed

Tags: juju, maas

I am having bootstrap failed in juju, I used the juju-quickstart -i and I am using MAAS as the environment.

I don't know why is this happening since I have all the nodes working and I took some prints.

Please help me :s

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPEyC.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Your nodes should be in states ready when you bootstrap Juju On MAAS. Make sure your nodes aren't in the state deployed before bootstrapping